# Why Dictionary Flag is working biased in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, facebook-graph-api, chatbot

Why **flagSelectTask** is working sometimes and sometimes not?

In the code below, When I type /reminder in chatbot the flag should be set to True and when I open webview it should check the condition and result accordingly. But If I clicks multiple times after closing a webview It returns either if block or else block. Why this is happening?

```
class Bot:
    flagSelectTask = {}

    def handleTextMessage(self,recipientID,messagingEvent):
        if textMessage.lower() == '/reminder':
            Bot.flagSelectTask[recipientID] = True # Select Task Webview Access Permission Granted
            return self.selectTaskWebView(recipientID)

    def selectTaskWebView(self,assignerID):

        messageData = {
            "recipient":{
                "id":assignerID
        },
        "message": {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "generic",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "title": "Please Select a Task",
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "type": "web_url",
                                "title": "Select",
                                "url": f"url.com/select-task/{assignerID}",
                                "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
                                "messenger_extensions": "true",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        }}}

        return self.sendAPI(messageData)

bot = Bot()

@app.route('/select-task/<string:assignerID>',methods=['GET'])
def selectTaskView(assignerID):

    if (assignerID in bot.flagSelectTask) and (bot.flagSelectTask[assignerID]):
        Task = bot.loadTasks(assignerID)
        log(Task)
        if len(Task)!=0:
            return render_template('tasks.html',tasks=Task)
        else:
            return '<b>You have not assigned any task yet</b>'
    else:
        return '<h1> Thank You. Please Restart If you want to send a reminder again.</h1>'
```

Comment: Please describe more detailed what you are doing and what the deseired and observed behaviour is.

Comment: @KlausD.Actually if I type /reminder then chatbot will send me a webview with task list if flagSelectTask contains assignerID and value is true. But If i click again on the webview after closing first attempt then else block of the route is executing. Why this is happening?